# storing app settings on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, settings

I need to store settings for my Google App Engine project. Currently I have:

```
class Settings(db.Model):
    rate = db.IntegerProperty(default=4)
    ...
```

And when I want to use it:

```
Settings.get_or_insert('settings')
```

This feels clumsy so is there a better way (without using Django)?

Comment: Will the settings change between deployments of versions of the application?

Comment: yeah, and can be updated during deployment too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please clarify what does "feel clumsy" to you about this -- that's not very clear to me.

The datastore is *the* way to persist updatable data in App Engine (blobstore's for huge blobs, memcache's not guaranteed persistent). If your settings can't be changed by the application of course you can just put them in your own custom `.yaml` file (or whatever, but yaml's how App Engine's own configuration files are already stored anyway...;-); just remember all such files are read-only from the application's viewpoint.  [YAML](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#YAML) is conveniently available to App Engine apps for parsing their own `.yaml` (but "read-only") files.

Comment: feels clumsy to me because I am forcing a model to have just a single instance

Comment: Richard, there is nothing at all wrong with having a singleton that is back by the datastore. The one thing that you really want to consider is that for performance reasons, you'll want to keep this entity in memcache, and write it to datastore whenever it changes.

Comment: @Adam, I entirely agree -- memcache's not guaranteed to _stay_ around, but it will be faster if it happens to;-).  @Richard, point is, the datastore's all you got (for persistent guaranteed storage). If you have many different "bits and pieces" that you need to persist, you could use an amorphous model to store any one of them (as a pickled blob), but that's not necessarily any more elegant.

Comment: thanks very much for the comments. I will make a class to wrap around the model and keep the data in memcache.

Comment: Memcache is superfluous. You only have one settings object - store it in a module level or class level variable instead. Nothing is faster than local memory access.

Comment: @Nick, if you're serving multiple requests at once, each of these simultaneous processes would have to load the config data from the datastore, if it wasn't _also_ in memcache (which they all can read from). So while (of course) using the cooy you already have in memory (if any) is fastest, that doesn't make memcache _superfluous_ it's a helpful addition to the memory+datastore combination for an app with sufficiently-high QPS peaks (doesn't take much: if typical response time is several seconds, even a fractional QPS peak can already have you serving w/multiple processes).  Right?

Comment: @Alex Given the relative infrequency of startup requests to regular requests, memcaching as well as storing it locally won't gain you much. My main point, though, is that Adam's comment suggests memcaching the config, when storing it on the local instance is _much_ faster for something that's small and required by every single request.

Comment: @Nick, I see, thanks -- indeed, relative frequency of process starts vs requests is key, and I guess it could be measured empirically for any given app (depends on how "time-clumped" its use is). And yes, of course you don't want to memcache it _instead of_ reusing the in-memory copy -- but with multiple simultaneous processes, if any one of them changes the config there had better be an easy way to make all others "invalidate their caches" (if such changes are very frequent, storing [[MC & DS]] at every change and reloading [[MC if there, else DS]] at every request may indeed be best!).

Answer (score 0):

In my projects, I put config data in the datastore (one record per config value) using this class:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Settings(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  value = ndb.StringProperty()

  @staticmethod
  def get(name):
    NOT_SET_VALUE = "NOT SET"
    retval = Settings.query(Settings.name == name).get()
    if not retval:
      retval = Settings()
      retval.name = name
      retval.value = NOT_SET_VALUE
      retval.put()
    if retval.value == NOT_SET_VALUE:
      raise Exception(('Setting %s not found in the database. A placeholder ' +
        'record has been created. Go to the Developers Console for your app ' +
        'in App Engine, look up the Settings record with name=%s and enter ' +
        'its value in that record\'s value field.') % (name, name))
    return retval.value
```

Your application would do this to get a value:

```
API_KEY = Settings.get('API_KEY')
```

If there is a value for that key in the datastore, you will get it. If there isn't, a placeholder record will be created and an exception will be thrown. The exception will remind you to go to the Developers Console and update the placeholder record.

I find this takes the guessing out of setting config values. If you are unsure of what config values to set, just run the code and it will tell you!